# Maximization of $||Ax||$ such that $Bx=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm having trouble maximizing the norm of $||Ax||$ such that $Bx=b$.
I set up a lagrange multiplier so that $L(x,\lambda) = x^T(A^TA)x - (Bx-b)^T\lambda$. (Say that $B$ is not invertible but $b$ is in the colspace so that the problem isn't trivial)

$\nabla_xL(x,\lambda) = 0 \Rightarrow 2(A^TA)x=B^T\lambda$

and $\nabla_\lambda L(x,\lambda) = 0 \Rightarrow Bx = b$.

If I assume that $A$ has full rank, then $x = \frac12 (A^TA)^{-1}B^T\lambda$.

If I plug it into the constraint, then $B(A^TA)^{-1}B^T\lambda = 2b$. 
How do I proceed solving for $\lambda$ here?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There is no maximum, i.e. you can select $x$ such that $\lVert Ax \rVert$ is arbitrarily large.

Because if $B x = b$ for some $x$, then $B(x+y)=b$ for all $y \in \operatorname{Ker} B$ and you can select $y$ arbitrarily large (assuming $A y \neq 0$).

If $B$ has full column rank then there is no optimization, because the solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If $B(A^TA)^{-1}B^T$ is full rank then $\lambda^* = 2(B(A^TA)^{-1}B^T)^{-1}b$ and
$$x^*= \frac12 (A^TA)^{-1}B^T\lambda^*= (A^TA)^{-1}B^T(B(A^TA)^{-1}B^T)^{-1}b$$

EDIT: see the comments below. This would be a correct answer for the minimization problem, but is a wrong answer to the maximization problem here.

Comment: If $B(A^TA)^{-1}B^T$ is full rank, either $B$ is square and invertible (which means there is no optimization anyway) or $B$ is wide in which case its null space is not trivial and $\lVert A x \rVert$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yes, I agree… I was minimizing $x^TA^TAx$ under $Bx=b$. Shall I delete my wrong answer or add this error in an edit?  The problem here is an interesting illustration for the case where the Lagrange conditions do not characterize the solution of the maximization problem.

Comment: Indeed, Lagrange multipliers can find local minima or maxima. This problem could be more interesting by maximizing $\lVert Ax \rVert / \lVert x \rVert$. But I think minimization problem is also interesting. It seems there is a lot of projections going on. I would be interested if someone could show these projections geometrically.

Comment: In econometrics, some orthogonal and nonorthogonal projections are sometimes illustrated geometrically. See for instance:   Ruud, P., 2000, An Introduction to Classical Econometric Theory, Oxford University Press.